# Convergence in $L^p$ of a limited martingale

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, martingales

I have a problem with the following exercise.

Let $(X_n)$ be a limited martingale (there exists $M>0$ such that for each $n$ is valid $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|<M)=1$). I have to prove that $X_n$ converges in $L^2$.

I know that for each $m>n$ is valid $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_m-X_n\right)^2\right] = \operatorname{Var}(X_m)-\operatorname{Var}(X_n)$ but I can not go on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Var$(X_m)$ is increasing and bounded and thus convergent. You thus get that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an $L^2$-Cauchy sequence.